# Asynchronous data and Views

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I loading asynchronous data on model with `this.store.find`, then I need to activate the **jQuery Slider**, but only after store returns with the slide paths.

I thought I need to call `this.$("#slides").slidesjs` in the View, but I couldn't do that after de `store` returns. Can someone help me?

Here is part of my code:

```
App.Slide = DS.Model.extend({
  src: DS.attr()
});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('slide');
  },
  afterModel: function(slides) {
    slides.forEach(function(item) {
      item.set('src', '/img/' + item.get('src'));
    });
  }
});
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  afterStoreReturns: function() { // i think would be some like this
    this.$("#slides").slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528
      });
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches I tend to follow.

#### The `didInsertElement` hook on the view, this isn't called again if the view isn't reinserted

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() { // i think would be some like this
    this.$("#slides").slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528
      });
  }
}
```

#### afterRender scheduled task, this one solves a problem where you might switch out the model, but not the view

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('slide');
  },
  afterModel: function(slides) {
    Em.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', function(){
      slides.forEach(function(item) {
        item.set('src', '/img/' + item.get('src'));
      });
    });
  }
});
```